# Can you add a note to an advanced filter?

Tags: excel, vba

When using an advanced filter in Excel, can you add a note/error code depending on the criteria?

For instance if I have criteria:

### Rep  | ID | Sales

Josh | 3  | <>10
 Tom  | 4  | <>10

Can I attach a note to the filtered results, so that I have an error column that might contain:

"Note where Josh's sales were not 10"

"Note where Tom's sales were not 10"

Here is my actual code:

```
Sub AdvancedFilter()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "FilteredData"
    End With
    Worksheets("FilteredData").Activate


        Sheets("DataSheet").Cells.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Criteria").Range("MyTable[#All]"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1"), Unique _
        :=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach I can think is to make a column in your table to determine if there is a comment or not, using VBA:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1).Comment Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = 1
    Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
    End If
Next i
```

After that, sort using this helper column (hide if 0, where 0 = no comment).

---

Edit1: I think I misunderstood the question on first read.

If you want to add a comment if a criteria is met, you can add comments using a loop:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1).Value < 10 Then
        Cells(i, 1).ClearComments
        Cells(i, 1).AddComment ("Sales not 10")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Yeah not a bad idea, I was just curious if there was a way within advanced filter itself, so that I don't have to loop through for many different criteria. 

But ultimately I guess a non-advanced filter method might be necessary to add comments for the different criteria.

Comment: @Gmiller I've not seen a comment/no comment option in advanced filter.  I have seen helper columns utilizing functions to count comments, or using the VBA comment count like i listed above.